# facebook app wont ask for extended permissions when validating

Tags: facebook, authentication, post, permissions, action

Have been trying for weeks, but my App won't ask for extended permissions, obviously that means that it wont POST to the timeline afterwards either.

```
require_once('/wp-content/php-sdk/src/facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'xxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxx',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($userID) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                array(
                                  'link' => 'www.theaandrdepartment.com/raw',
                                  'message' => 'I just helped an Aussie band make it to    
radio play! By voting, you can too.'
                             ));
echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
```

}

```
} else { $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                   'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                   ));
        header("Location: ".$login_url);
     }
```

If anyone could help that would amazing.

I copied most of this code straight from the Facebook example, but to no avail.

Comment: So what does your actual login URL look like? (Btw., asking for so many permissions straight away might deter users from using your app at all. You should only ask for permissions at the point you actually need them, and asking for read and write permissions at the same time is also discouraged – have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/10/09/3-ways-to-boost-your-facebook-login-conversion-rate-above-70/)

Comment: Hey buddy, i took your advice and am only asking for Publish_stream.But still no love.

Comment: The login works now, is asking the right permissions, but now just can't post to /me/feed. 

I'm a noob at this stuff, so if someone felt super generous and email me, I'm sure my client would compensate(lukehart0403@gmail.com)